# MySQL Query Optimisation for a Form Based Application

Tags: mysql, performance, drop-down-menu, query-optimization

**Scenario :**
I am working on a form based project. Here all the records will be stored in a table called ModuleTable. Now I am having a select field (aka drop down field) in the form. All the options of the select field will be mapped to a unique id and stored in a separate table say PickListTable. In ModuleTable, whenever a record is created, this uniqueID will be stored for the chosen option. The basic table design is described in this below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrHcR.png)

**Case :** Need a better optimised way to replace UniqueID with option value in query.

**SOLUTIONS TRIED :-**

Here CONCAT function is used only as example. The user can provide any function and also the number of fields also increases dynamically.

**1. Joins**
Simply joining both the tables. The issue is, when the number of fields grow, then the number of joins also grows drastically.

Query Sample :

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(Select1.VALUE, Select2.VALUE) AS 'Select Value' 
FROM ModuleTable 
LEFT JOIN PickListTable Select1 ON ModuleTable.SelectField1 = Select1.UniqueID 
LEFT JOIN PickListTable Select2 ON ModuleTable.SelectField2 = Select2.UniqueID;
```

**2. Sub-Query**
By using sub-query to resolve select values. This is better than join method. But when I use the same in ORDER BY / WHERE Clause, it takes above 1 min to query the same.

Query Sample :

```
SELECT ID, 
 CONCAT((SELECT VALUE FROM PickListTable WHERE UniqueID = SelectField1), 
 (SELECT VALUE FROM PickListTable WHERE UniqueID = SelectField2)) 
FROM ModuleTable 
WHERE CONCAT((SELECT VALUE FROM PickListTable WHERE UniqueID = SelectField1), 
      (SELECT VALUE FROM PickListTable WHERE UniqueID = SelectField2)) 
LIKE '%hello%';
```

Do we have any better approaches to resolve the same?

Comment: Please add sample data as text rather than linked images AND include module table.

Comment: I do not really understand your data structure! If you have columns of selectfield1 and 2 in your main table, then why do you need an EAV-like secondary table to store its values? Store the values directly in selectfield1 and 2 columns and no join s necessary.

Comment: @Shadow The reason is in this kinda design, when an option value is updated. I don't need to run update for my entire module table.

Comment: Are moduletable and entitytable synonyms? if so clarify in question if not add moduletable

Comment: Yes,. Both are same

Comment: @Bala As you are realising, you need to do as many joins as you have a number of lookup columns. If the number of lookup columns can change in the future, then you are looking at dynamic properties, which is at odds with relational theory and sql. Both of these expect a known and stable data structure in the first place. You may have to explore nosql solutions or choose db structure in mysql that can handle dynamic properties, but the latter will have compromises, no matter which design you go with.